# What is wrong with my makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I am unable to write a makefile that works. I have read the following tutorial (*) and I see that we can write simple files such as:

```
program : program.cpp
    g++ -o program program.cpp -lm
```

(*) http://www.pma.caltech.edu/~physlab/make.html

I tried to adpt the example to suit my own needs, but it is not working:

```
interpreter: gvr_v51.c gvr_v51_interpreter.h
   gcc gvr_v51_interpreter.h gvr_v51.c -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -o gvr_v51 -lSDL

parser: gvr_v51_parser.h gvr_v51.c
    gcc gvr_v51_parser.h gvr_v51.c -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -o gvr_v51 -lSDL
```

What I need to achieve is to be able to allow the user to compile by typing either "make interpreter" or "make parser". The difference between the two is that the first will include the header gvr_v51_interpreter.h, while the other will include the header gvr_v51_parser.h

Both header files are identical, except for one #define line that holds different value in the two files. The remaining contents of the header files include the declaration of structs, enums, as well as functions prototypes.

Is what I want to achieve even possible? If so, could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Documents/GvR$ make interpreter
gcc gvr_v51_interpreter.h gvr_v51.c -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -o gvr_v51 -lSDL
In file included from gvr_v51.c:3:0:
gvr_v51_file_handling.c: In function ‘check_args’:
gvr_v51_file_handling.c:6:18: error: ‘ARGC_EXPECTED’ undeclared (first use in this function)
gvr_v51_file_handling.c:6:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
gvr_v51_file_handling.c:7:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: You could just use the -DInterpreter then put #ifdef in the header. Its a better way to do it than have two identical files ... but i don't know why that isn't working

Comment: This was a sample of the errors I get. In all, I have 25k rows of errors and Ubuntu crashes every time I type make interpreter...

Comment: Does `gvr_v51.c` have an `#include` directive? Which header does it call for?

Comment: I assume I make a very basic mistake. The program compiles just fine when when I insert "#include gvr_v51_interpreter.h" in the gvr_v51.c file and when I type in the terminal: "gcc -pedantic -Wall -stc=c99 ./gvr_v51.c -o gvr -lSDL"

Comment: gvr_v51.c includes other .c files, but not these headers. Before I tried to use the make utility, the file gvr_v51.c did have #include gvr_v51_interpreter.h and it compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include header files by appending them to the list of c files to compile. However you can include a header depending on the definition of a macro and predefine it with a gcc option.

In gvr_v51.c:

```
#ifdef INTERPRETER
#include "gvr_v51_interpreter.h"
#else
#include "gvr_v51_parser.h"
#endif
```

In the Makefile:

```
interpreter:
    gcc -lSDL -DINTERPRETER -o gvr_v51 gvr_v51.c

parser:
    gcc -lSDL -o gvr_v51 gvr_v51.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include header files conditionally without altering the source file (`gvr_v51.c`):

```
interpreter: gvr_v51.c gvr_v51_interpreter.h
    gcc -include gvr_v51_interpreter.h gvr_v51.c -pedantic ...
parser: gvr_v51_parser.h gvr_v51.c
    gcc -include gvr_v51_parser.h gvr_v51.c -pedantic ...
```

Once that's working, there are several ways to improve it. In particular, I urge you not to have two rules that build `gvr_v51`, neither of them called `gvr_v51`.